# How to get inserted data from a query to database as success message?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

i'm working for a project and this problem came across me as i'm not a master in php and mysql.
here is the sample.

table

id(AI)-fname-lname

```
<php
include 'db.php';
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(`fname`, `lname`) VALUES('some', 'one')");
if($query==1)
{
     //some code
}
```

this is working fine, i can know whether the Query is Successful or not. what i want to know is, how to get the data of the row i just inserted, so that i can use the 'id' in another related table...
hoping for positive responce..

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get id of recent inserted record using `mysql_insert_id()` 
by using that id you can get records using select  query

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(`fname`, `lname`) VALUES('some', 'one')");
$id=mysql_insert_id();

$select_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table where id=".$id."");


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this function

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

This will return you the last inserted id with specific database connection. Also you don't want to get the data inserted other than id, because you already have it while inserting row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

This will give the id to which the data is inserted, you can use that id for further use.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the key ID of the row

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```